# get text in "<li>" tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I wanna get a list of `li` tag text.

I got the tag list `lis` to work but I doesn't assign the text content to my `country` object.

Script

```
    var lis = document.getElementById("navbar").getElementsByTagName("li");
        var url = '@Url.Action("Paychart", "Pivot")';
        var country;
        for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++)
        {
            country[i] = lis[i].textContent;
        }
```

HTML

```
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <li class="ui-state-default">@item</li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to initiate the `country`, e.g. `var country = {};`, or else you will get an error at this line `country[i] = lis[i].textContent;`

Second, I suggest, instead of doing this

```
    var lis = document.getElementById("navbar").getElementsByTagName("li");
```

use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), and it could replace the above like this

```
    var lis = document.querySelectorAll("#navbar li");
```

Stack snippet

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("#navbar li");

var url = '@Url.Action("Paychart", "Pivot")';
var country = {};
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  country[i] = lis[i].textContent;
}

console.log(country)
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">@item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">@item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">@item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">@item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @DenizOzogul And now you are able to upvote answer as well :)